# Cypress: select random option when my dropdown is loaded based on other field

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-testing

In cypress test framework, I want to wait until my dropdown is populated by API data based on other field value then select a random option from the populated options. I have tried several ways which are not working as expected, the only that is working is when my populated options have fixed length the following code works, but I cannot ensure this length because the options could be any number of items based on what is entered in the other field.

```
cy.get('#relatedTopics')
       .find('option').should('be.length', 2)
       .then($elm => $elm.get(1).setAttribute('selected', "selected"))
       .parent()
       .trigger('change')
```

Comment: Cypress is not waiting for my dropdown to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to add information of how many items there will be in total to separate html element and then wait for correct number of of items to appear.

Other way would be to store information of populated data somehow accessible to this test and again use information to wait for correct number of items.

There are many more ways to do it, but it is impossible to tell which would be good in your particular case. I would probably not be generating so random test data that it would be a problem or at least I would have had record of all generated data at hand all times.

Comment: my dropdown is very dynamic, we cannot predict how many values would be populated. Even if I specify a fixed number that would change at anytime and my test case would fail. I would want cypress to wait for dropdown to be loaded with more than one value and pick one of it randomly

Comment: And my answer did address the case where you just figure out before hand how many items there are going to be... If you cannot change the code in webpage to provide that information, then you need to get it from some other way. For example you could do manually similar XHR request to backend to get the number of results or use cypress as middleman to get the results of XHR query which populates the list and then use that information to wait for exactly correct number of elements to appear...

Comment: If you just want a hacky way to monitor it you can always just wait for 5 seconds, then query number of elements in list and use that numeber as a basis for random selection limits...